# How to write jcl to make dbdgen

Tags: jcl, ims-db

I write jcl 4 dbdgen:

```
//C      EXEC PGM=ASMA90,REGION=8M,                              
//            PARM=(OBJECT,NODECK,NODBCS,'SIZE(MAX,ABOVE)')      
//SYSIN    DD DSN=USER19.DBDSRC(LIBDBD),DISP=SHR                 
//SYSLIB   DD DSN=DFSD10.SDFSMAC,DISP=SHR                        
//SYSLIN   DD UNIT=SYSDA,DISP=(,PASS),                           
//            SPACE=(80,(100,100),RLSE),                         
//            DCB=(BLKSIZE=80,RECFM=F,LRECL=80)                  
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                           
//SYSUT1   DD UNIT=SYSDA,DISP=(,DELETE),                         
//            SPACE=(CYL,(10,5))                                                                                               
//L      EXEC PGM=HEWL,PARM='XREF,LIST',                         
//            COND=(0,LT,C),REGION=120K                          
//SYSLIN   DD DSN=*.C.SYSLIN,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)                   
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                           
//SYSLMOD  DD DISP=SHR,                                          
//            DSN=USER19.DBDLIB(LIBDBD)                          
//SYSUT1   DD UNIT=(SYSDA,SEP=(SYSLMOD,SYSLIN)),                 
//            SPACE=(1024,(100,10),RLSE),DISP=(,DELETE)
```

And have 8 rc.

I think, that it is problem with asma, am i right?
  Have anybody any ideas to repair my programm?>

Comment: You need to look at the spool file created. An RC if eight does not tell much specifically, and no-one looking at what you've provided can even be sure about which step produced the eight. Look at the spool file, you'll find messages. Look up the messages (poke them in a search-engine, should take you to the description within the IBM Knowledge Centre). If you can't get it from that, update your question with the messages and any other output you think may be relevant.

Comment: sorry. My que wasn't correct. all problem with my dbd. When I have dbd without any sons , i get my dbdlib, another way i have rc0, and error ASMA254I AND SYS MSG:
SEGM    NAME=SON,PARENT=VENDRSEG,TYPE=SEQ,BYTES=20    
8,SEGM110 - SEGM SPECIFICATION LIMIT EXCEEDED.        
8,SEGM150  PHY. PARENT PARAMETER IS OMITTED OR INVALID
FIELD   NAME=(SONNAME,SEQ),BYTES=20,START=1,TYPE=C    
DBDGEN                                                
8,DGEN110 - DBDGEN TERMINATED; ERRORS IN DBD.         
FINISH                                                
END